# Expanding river width on raster based DEM in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

[image]

How do I expand the river width on a raster based DEM in ArcMap?

For example, my DEM has 20 m cell size, and I want that my river is wide 3x that everywhere (60 m in total, or 3 cell wide). I have river centerline too and I do not want to change the current elevations, I actually want to expand the center box elevation to adjacent 2 cells from each side of the river.

Comment: Clarification - what do you mean when you say you don't want to change the current elevations but you do want to expand the center box elevation? Do you mean you want to create a new copy of the DEM where the river cells are all the same height at both center and edge pixels?

Comment: please edit your question with more details (and maybe a small sketch) of what you need.Do you want to take the DEM into account or make a buffer around your river ?

Comment: Hello. I want to expand my river bed (on a DEM) to 3 cell wide channel, and it is 1 cell wide at the moment. I don't want constant bed elevation along the stream, I just want to expand the existing bathymetry laterally.

Answer (score 1):

You could explore the [Expand](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/expand.htm) tool.

If you have a rasterized version of your river network, then run it on that.